# Show $\sqrt{2}sin(2\pi(n+1/2)x)$ is an orthonormal system.

Tags: real-analysis

Exercise: Show that $f_n(x)=\sqrt{2}sin(2\pi(n+1/2)x)$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$ defines an orthonormal system on $[0,1]$. Hint use Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

$Proof$

Let $g(x)=\sqrt{2}sin(\pi x)$ where $g\in pc[0,1]$ (piecewise continuous functions on $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$). We will prove $f_n(x)$ is an orthonormal system by showing that
$$ \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\langle g(x),f_n(x)\rangle \rightarrow 0 $$
which would follow from the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Observe then that
$$ \langle g(x),f_n(x)\rangle=\int^{1}_{0}2\sin(\pi x)\sin(2\pi(n+\frac{1}{2})x)dx $$
Since
$$ \sin(a)\sin(b)=\frac{1}{2}[\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)] $$
we have that
$$ \int^{1}_{0}2\sin(\pi x)\sin(2\pi(n+1/2)x)dx=\int^{1}_{0}\cos(2\pi nx) - \cos(2\pi nx + 2\pi x)$$
$$= \frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{2\pi n}-\frac{\sin(2\pi nx + 2\pi x)}{2\pi n+ 2\pi}\Big|^{1}_{0} $$
Since $\sin(2\pi n +x)=\sin(x)$, we have that
$$=\frac{-\sin(2\pi n+2\pi)}{2\pi n+2\pi}=\frac{-\sin(2\pi)}{2\pi n+2\pi}=0 $$
This completes the proof.

Is my reasoning correct? I did prove this before without using the lemma (At least I believe I have), but wanted to see if I could prove it by using this lemma as indicated by the hint.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of an 'orthonormal system'?

Comment: $\langle f_n,f_m \rangle = 1$ if $n=m$ and $0$ if $n\neq m$.

Comment: Also $\langle f_n,f_m \rangle =\int^{1}_{0}f_n(x)\overline{f_m}(x)dx.$

Comment: How does $\left<g,f_n\right>=0$ show $\left<f_n,f_m\right>=\delta_{mn}$?